# Volume of $n$-sphere with recurrence relations

Tags: calculus, geometry

On [Wikipedia][1], there is a discussion of recurrence relations between volumes $S_n$ of $n$-spheres and volumes $V_n$ of $n$-balls. Putting two recurrence relations together can give us the volume of all spheres. They are $$S_n=(n+1)V_{n+1}\tag{1}$$$$S_{n+2}=2\pi V_{n+1} \tag{2}$$

The first one I understand fine; the second one, not so much. I don't understand the explanation they give on the Wikipedia page...there's a period floating around in the integrand whose meaning I don't know, and I'm not sure what they're doing with $R$.

Can anyone explain (2) to me?

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_sphere#Recurrences

Comment: A better explanation is h[ere.](http://divisbyzero.com/2010/05/09/volumes-of-n-dimensional-balls/)

Comment: That is nice. I'm still wondering how to find a relation between $V_n$ and $S_{n+1}$ though.